# LineBox is misaligned when emoji is present

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, unicode, urwid

Running this code:

```
import urwid

icon = u"\U0001F600"

top = urwid.Padding(
        urwid.LineBox(
            urwid.Filler(urwid.Text(icon, align="center")
                         )), width=10)

urwid.MainLoop(top).run()
```

Displays this:
[image]

Why is the LineBox misaligned? Any ideas or solution?

Comment: It's fairly clear why this is happening. `urwid` thinks `u"\U0001F600"` is two characters wide, not one. The docs say the module has a basic understanding of character widths, but it seems as though emojis are not basic in that sense. They are not in Unicode's Basic Multilingual Plane.

Comment: Yeah, I reported that already to them. I am waiting for a response from @wardi. You can find the issue [here](https://github.com/urwid/urwid/issues/225)

Comment: note that [not every characters will fit in the monospace font width](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/2978/81481)

Comment: Cool bug report! I've bumped into the same issue some days ago while preparing a presentation with [presentty](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/presentty) but didn't have time to dig much -- now I understand better what happened.

Comment: @AmanAgrawal btw, you're the fellow behind zulip-terminal, right? nice work! I tried it out some days ago. I'd totally use it if it had a way to navigate among threads. =)